# AP2112 LDO - maximum output current

Tags: datasheet, ldo

In my design I'm using the [AP2112](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809192242_Diodes-Incorporated-AP2112K-3-3TRG1_C51118.pdf) LDO 3.3V version to drive a simple breakout board that has an STM32F030x, a CH340C USB-UART bridge, a dual inverter gate IC and three 1mA LEDs. All of that should draw no more than ~10mA given that there is no power signal involved, just TTL stuff.

The AP2112 seems perfect for this, but in the datasheet the maximum output current is given as 600mA, minimal value.
[image]

At first glance I understood that I had to draw at least 600mA otherwise the LDO wouldn't work, but of course this is not true, I can draw much less and that is the maximum value.

Is there a specific reason why they used the **Min** column instead of the **Typ** column?

I think that would have been more clear.

Comment: It is telling you the max output current is at least 600mA. You might be able to get more, but they don’t guarantee it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there a specific reason why they used the Min column instead of the
> Typ column?*

Yes, it's saying that they guarantee a \$\color{red}{\text{maximum}}\$ output current of at least 600 mA. Think about what it would mean if they used the typical column <-- would that tell you how much output current they guarantee for each and every device they sold?

[image]

Comment: Ohh right, the datasheet is unique but all the thousand of AP2112's are not.

Comment: Correct; it has to try and cater for all devices sold.